# highcharts datetime x-axis extents differ between two charts with same range

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisb911/4xnymdrf/13/), example I've got two instances of the same chart. Each has two series of data - one common to both with the same max and min and the other different but with values wholey within the extents of the first series. What i'm expecting is to see the two graphs to the same scale. What I get is the first shrunk to the middle of the graph range and the second full width.

I've tried all sorts - setting the max and min etc, but really, I don't understand what the issue is so i'm having trouble figuring out what to do about it

Can anyone tell me what's going one - why don't they scale the same and what can I do to force them to? I've added some buttons to print the extremes and they report as being the same. I've tried setting min and max on the series to the min and max values from my data - but to no avail.

```
    var gc2 = [
    [1421680291000, 5],
    [1421690785000, 5],
    [1421713693000, 1],
    [1421746462000, 6],
    [1421747928000, 6],
    [1421754240000, 6],
    [1421775733000, 6],
    [1421782226000, 6],
    [1421798460000, 6],
    [1421884860000, 3],
    [1421971260000, 6],
    [1422057660000, 6],
    [1422144060000, 6],
    [1422230460000, 6],
    [1422268738000, 3],
    [1422273729000, 1],
    [1422316860000, 1],
    [1422663082000, 5],
    [1422748860000, 6],
    [1422835260000, 3],
    [1422921660000, 6],
    [1423180860000, 3],
    [1423267260000, 5],
    [1423353660000, 3],
    [1423440060000, 5],
    [1423872060000, 5],
    [1423958460000, 5]
];


var bad = [
    [1421971260000, 1],
    [1422057660000, 1],
    [1422144060000, 1],
    [1422230460000, 1],
    [1422268738000, 1],
    [1422748860000, 1]
];


var good = [
    [1421746462000, 1],
    [1421747928000, 1],
    [1421754240000, 1],
    [1421775733000, 1],
    [1421782226000, 1],
    [1421798460000, 1]
];

$(document).ready(function () {
    checkOrder(gc2);
    checkOrder(good);
    checkOrder(bad);
});

function checkOrder(series) {
    var xlow = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
        if (series[i][0] < xlow) {
            console.log("out of order");
        } else {
            xlow = series[i][0];
        }
    }
}

$(function () {

    $('#container1').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            defaultSeriesType: 'column',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'

        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'not working'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type:'datetime'
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'x1',
            data: gc2,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }, {
            name: 'x2',
            data: bad,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });

});

$(function () {

    $('#container2').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            defaultSeriesType: 'column',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'

        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'working'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type:'datetime'
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'x1',
            data: gc2,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }, {
            name: 'x',
            data: good,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });

});
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't contain two charts, just your snippet.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q9ot0nbv/2/

Comment: Also you have Highcharts error 15 which means you haven't sorted your data.

Comment: Hi - not sure what happened with the jsfiddle - hopefully its ok now. Really not sure how you got a higcharts error 15  - the data is in order (I've added a function to check and all seems ok?)

Comment: look at your **g1** for instance. Your UTC dates are not sorted! At some point you have `1421746462000` after that `1422057660000` which the second one is bigger. After the second one data should be bigger, which isn't (`1421754240000` is smaller than `1422057660000`)

Comment: many apologies - I think the jsfiddle was out of date. I've updated it and it shows both charts with the problem. The g1 data instance wasn't actually used - i've simplified it as much as I can but I still get the same problem. Any insights gratefully received...

Comment: This is interesting...

Comment: It's caused by point-ranges, which looks like improperly calculated (because of differences between data points) - you can set `pointRange` option: http://jsfiddle.net/4xnymdrf/15/ - to be the same on the charts or just calculate like in the example.

Comment: fanastic - fixes my issue so thanks a lot. Whats the difference between setting the range as in your example and simply setting it to '1' which seems to cure the issue too?